# How to structure multilayered 2d tilemap in multidimensional array?

Tags: javascript

I am using javascript for developing an html5 game using the webgl render engine. But for now I think it's better to ask and explain it in general.

For the 2d tilegame I am using an multidimensional array for structuring x,y coordinates of tile properties.

This is how my structure looks now:
http://pastebin.com/mtLMW8hd

The loop for the tilemap will loop through each x,y coordinate and draw the layers from the layerx property.

I am using an tilesheet to draw the tiles so 
the ImageId = tilesheet id
tileId = index of tile on the tilesheet.

Here is an visual explanation of my structure:
[image]

These are my questions based on structuring multilayered 2d tilemap:

- Is it performance based better to use variable names/object properties to define layers or an array of layers ? ("layers":[{property:value},{property:value},{property:value}]

  - If i'm using an array of layers how can i define for example layer 4 without having to define layer 1 and 2?
- Is there or do you have an better solution(can also be performance based)?

Please use javascript/json for example code